# How can I remove rust cargo from my PATH after installing rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have `~/.cargo/bin` in $PATH since I installed rust and cargo using `curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh`. I can't find where `.cargo/bin` is added to my PATH anywhere (my default shell is zsh). I want to remove it from my PATH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I struggled with the same issue for *months* until I finally found what was going on. Cargo is automatically added to your path in the `~/.zprofile` file (`~/.profile` for Bash users), with the line `export PATH="$HOME/.cargo/bin:$PATH"`. **Removing this line fixes the issue.**

I hope this helps whoever was searching for this answer because I didn't find one anywhere.

Comment: I have the same problem but with Bash and I don't have a `~/.zprofile`.  In Bash it gets stored inside the `~/.profile`

Comment: Thanks, @PRouleau, for the comment! I'll edit my answer.